# Code gets stuck in infinite loop unless I'm debugging it / set a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a number of `DropDownList` controls and a single `TextBox`. Depending on the selected values in the `DropDownList` controls, the software should either:

- Sum the DDL's values and put it in the textbox, and make it read-only
- Enable the textbox for user input

When they tab out of the textbox, it validates their input to make sure it's a valid value (must be X, Y, or Z and if it's Z it has some 'extra' logic).

Each of my `DropDownList` controls calls a method, `SumValues()`, when its selected value changes.

`SumValues()` performs the logic dictated in the bullets above. After it assigns the sum to the textbox, or enables it for free-form user data entry, it calls `BlurMyTextbox` (which is also assigned to the textbox's `onblur` event / attribute) because when this value changes, it will modify *another* set of controls depending on the textbox's value.

`BlurMyTextbox()` does the following:

```
function BlurMyTextbox()
{
    var cmb = $("#cmbV14").data("kendoDropDownList"); //get reference to 'child' drop down
    var val = $("#txtMyTextbox").val(); //get this value
    if (val == 'x' || val == 'y')
    {
        //set data source on child drop down if textbox value is valid
        // this condition occurs when SumValues() auto-enters the value
        // this functionality works fine
        var OneAndDash = [{ "Text": "1", "Value": "1" }, { "Text": "-", "Value": "-" }];
        cmb.dataSource.data(OneAndDash);
    }
    else
    {
        if (val != someGlobalVar && someOtherGlobalVar > 0)
        {
            // if value is outside of a particular range, show error
            var template = kendo.template(validationTemplate)({
                text: 'Invalid input; field must be X, Y, or Z'
                , buttons: [{ id: 'btnOk', text: 'Ok', click: 'ClosePopup("Validation");' }]
            });
            OpenWindow('Validation', 'Information', { content: template, actions: '', confirm: true, draggable: true });

            //clear textbox and give it focus so they enter the correct value
            $("#txtMyTextbox").val('');
            $("#txtMyTextbox").focus();
        }

        // assign different datasource to dependent drop down
        var ZeroToOneAndDashData = [{ "Text": "0", "Value": "0" }, { "Text": "1", "Value": "1" }, { "Text": "-", "Value": "-" }];
        cmb.dataSource.data(ZeroToOneAndDashData);
        // this drop down does not effect the textbox in any way
        // nor does it call BlurMyTextbox or anything like that
    }
}
```

So it checks the value assigned to it, then it does either:

- Assigns a data set to the child control
- Conditionally shows an error and clears + re-focuses the textbox, and assigns a different data set to the child control

When I run my software, as soon as I change a value in any of the dropdowns that calls `SumValues()` (which in turn calls `BlurMyTextbox`), it repeatedly shows the popup over and over and I can't click it to dismiss it. If I set a breakpoint on the `OpenWindow` call in `BlurMyTextbox`, it only pops up once and I can dismiss it and the software behaves as expected.

I see no indication in the Call Stack as to what could be causing this infinite loop. There's got to be some sort of logical error, but I can't identify it...

Comment: Where is the code for the `SumValues()` function?

Comment: I didn't include it as it's quite lengthy, but the extent of it's functionality is basically just `$("txtMyTextBox").val(someValue);`, then it sets the `.readOnly`, `.tabIndex`, `.css` properties for `txtMyTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, as I finally decide to ask the question I find my solution:

Displaying the popup causes the Textbox to lose focus, which calls Blur, which sees the value is invalid and shows the popup... which causes the textbox to lose focus etc. etc.

Removing the `$("#txtMyTextBox").focus()` call fixes this behavior, as it no longer tries to alternate between focusing on the textbox and the popup.